# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str in python POST request

Tags: python, curl, post, methods

Hi im trying to send POST to API of Bitcoin exchange

my code is:

```
def exchange(method,params):
   key = "XXXXX"
   secret = "XXXX"
   params["method"] = method
   params ["time"] = time.time()
   urllib.parse.urlencode()
   sign = hashlib.sha256(params,"","&")
   sign = json.dumps(sign)
   headers = ["key:" + key, "hash:" + sign]
   headers = json.dumps(headers)
   req = urllib2.Request('https://XXXX/api/')
   req.add_header(headers)
   r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   return  


exchange(["getinfo"],["s"])
```

i have

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

only response.

Have you idea how to format this data?

Comment: Why are you adding the headers as JSON?

Comment: i read that in instruction of api. shouldnt i? they has only php instruction https://bitbay.net/pl/api-prywatne

Comment: `req.add_header()` also takes **two** parameters. Can you please include the **full traceback** of the exception so we can actually pinpoint where the exception is thrown and how Python got to that point?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i pasted all of code and there is instruction https://bitbay.net/pl/api-prywatne of api

Comment: Then *read the Python `urllib2` documentation first*. No, that's not how you add headers. The PHP code doesn't encode the HTTP headers to JSON either. I also note that you got the header names wrong, the API looks for `API-Key` and `API-Hash`.

Comment: You didn't post the *traceback*. The full error message that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stoploss.py", line 34, in <module>
    exchange(["getinfo"],["s"])
  File "stoploss.py", line 22, in exchange
    params["method"] = method
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Note that in PHP `array` is most often best transslated as a *dictionary* in Python, not a list.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information.

Comment: And the query is also not JSON encoded. It is form encoded instead.

Comment: You probably want to look at [How do I sign a POST request using HMAC-SHA512 and the Python requests library?](//stackoverflow.com/a/42100642), where I show how to use the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to encode the http POST body first before creating the signature.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hmmm it looks good. Will it be a problem if you rewrite that to Bitbay API?

Comment: I'm not going to do that now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
params["method"] = method
```

This is the line you are getting the error in. You are trying to iterate through an array with a string, which does not make sense. The value in the square brackets has to be an integer not a string.

Comment: sho how should i change it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line? The array params only has one element - ["s"]

Comment: its my overcombinated param, that should be empty

Comment: Can you explain it in more details?

Comment: hmm so how to rewrite params["method"] to dictionary?